# Invalid hook call on RNPickerSelect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-picker-select

I am building my first react-native app for both android and IOS. In order for my app to function, I need to use RNPickerSelect. But for some reason when I try to do

```
<RNPickerSelect 
              onValueChange={(value) => setOrgin(value)}
              value={orgin}
              useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
              items={countries} placeholder={{label: "Country of Orgin", value: null}} style={pickerSelectStyles}
          />
```

on android I get "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. " How can I solve this issue

Comment: seems issue is not there in this code, You have used any of hooks outside of a function body, try to remove that and check.

Comment: I checked that but it works fine when the RNPickerSelect is not in the code, but when I add it, it gives me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue is here, I have tried with `npm i react-native-picker-select --legacy-peer-deps` as turkun mentioned and it seems working me too.
Node version may have effect for the fix, I have v12.22.12.

Answer (score 1):

I have re-install the module with this command => npm i react-native-picker-select --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 1):

re-install the module with this command => npm i react-native-picker-select --legacy-peer-deps ... works for me also.
Probably a conflict on expo dependencies.
It works with Expo but no more when creating de app bundle with eas.
This module is no longer supported. I change by using this : https://github.com/ouroboroscoding/react-native-picker